# Counting successor combinations in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, counting

I got a `data.frame` that looks like the following one:

```
OBJECT ID   TASK
1           A
1           C
1           D
1           E
2           A
2           B
2           C
2           D
2           F
```

Now I would like to count the unique successive combinations within the `data.frame` in order to get following result:

```
PREDECESSOR  SUCCESSOR  COUNT
A            C          1
C            D          2
D            E          1
A            B          1
B            C          1
D            F          1
```

I've already figured out to extract the successive values with the help of two `for` loops, but I'm failing the assignment and counting task within a new `data.frame` (or `list`).

Comment: Have a look at package `igraph`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aggregate(COUNT~.,
          data.frame(PREDECESSOR = head(df1$TASK, -1),
                     SUCCESSOR = tail(df1$TASK, -1),
                     COUNT = 1),
          length)
#  PREDECESSOR SUCCESSOR COUNT
#1           E         A     1
#2           A         B     1
#3           A         C     1
#4           B         C     1
#5           C         D     2
#6           D         E     1
#7           D         F     1
```

You could use a similar approach even if you want to first `split` by `OBJECT.ID`

```
temp = do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df1, df1$OBJECT.ID), function(X){
    aggregate(COUNT~., data.frame(PREDECESSOR = head(X$TASK, -1),
                                  SUCCESSOR = tail(X$TASK, -1),
                                  COUNT = 1),
              length)
}))

aggregate(COUNT~., temp, length)
#  PREDECESSOR SUCCESSOR COUNT
#1           A         C     1
#2           B         C     1
#3           C         D     2
#4           D         E     1
#5           A         B     1
#6           D         F     1
```

**DATA**

```
df1 = structure(list(OBJECT.ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), TASK = c("A", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", "F")), .Names = c("OBJECT.ID", 
"TASK"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: The second approach is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for your fast reply!

Answer (score 2):

Solution using `data.table`:

Code:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, TASK0 := shift(TASK), OBJECT]
df[!is.na(TASK0), .N, .(TASK, TASK0)][, .(
    COUNT = sum(N)), .(PREDECESSOR = TASK0, SUCCESSOR = TASK)]
```

Result:

```
   PREDECESSOR SUCCESSOR COUNT
1:           A         C     1
2:           C         D     2
3:           D         E     1
4:           A         B     1
5:           B         C     1
6:           D         F     1
```

Explanation:

- `setDT(df)`: turns data.frame into a data.table object
- `[, TASK0 := shift(TASK), OBJECT]`: gets previous letter for each `OBJECT`
- `!is.na(TASK0)`: gets rid of first row for each `OBJECT` (they don't have `PREDECESSOR`)
- `.N, .(TASK, TASK0)`: counts occurences of `TASK` and `TASK0` (previous letter combinations)
- `sum(N)`: sums counts

Data (`df`):

```
structure(list(OBJECT = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    TASK = c("A", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", "F")), .Names = c("OBJECT", 
"TASK"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to get the counts, you do it with the following two lines:

```
cc <- cbind(df$TASK,c(df$TASK[-1],"LAST"))
table(paste(cc[,1],cc[2],sep="-"))
```

The result is

```
A-B  A-C  B-C  C-D  D-E  D-F  E-A F-LAST 
1    1    1    2    1    1    1   1
```